# MySQL information_schema change COLLATIONS IS_DEFAULT

Tags: mysql, collation, percona, mysql-5.7, xtradb

I'm having problems with setting the default collation for the utf8mb4 and utf8 charsets on a Percona XtraDB setup. If I write a query such as this:

```
SET @ue = 'test@email.com';

SET @u = (SELECT u.ID FROM db.users u 
WHERE u.user_email = @ue);
```

It fails with the below message:

```
/* SQL Error (1267): Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '=' */
```

This seems to be because the **collation_connection** session value is always being set as utf8mb4_general_ci. The global value for that variable is **utf8_unicode_ci**, which is still not quite right but more preferable.

I cannot for the life of me find where that session variable is coming from. I've had a look inside **information_schema.COLLATIONS** and can see that **utf8_general_ci** and **utf8mb4_general_ci** are as follows:

```
--------------------------------------------------------
| COLLATION_NAME     | CHARACTER_SET_NAME | IS_DEFAULT |
--------------------------------------------------------
| utf8_general_ci    | utf8               | Yes        |
--------------------------------------------------------
| utf8mb4_general_ci | utf8mb4            | Yes        |
--------------------------------------------------------
```

And yet I really don't want these collations as the default?

I've tried putting these values in each of the nodes `my.cnf` files and it doesn't seem to have any impact:

```
[mysqld]
character-set-server=utf8
collation-server=utf8_unicode_ci
skip-character-set-client-handshake
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: As it happens, I just put live an article on collations and conversions, I wonder if it might help shed some light? https://www.percona.com/community-blog/2018/06/12/character-sets-migrating-utf8b4-pt_online_schema_change/
Disclosure: I work for Percona.

Comment: What parameters are you using when connecting?

Comment: @RickJames nothing in particular, just the default ones that Workbench and Heidi connect with. How can I see the parameters?